# Json pairs to rows

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am back on attacking SQL Server 2016 with JSON documents. I have had some luck through deep digging through the net, however I still cannot figure out how to turn my json results into rows with multiple value columns.

I was looking to create something like this:

```
+-----------+-------+------------+-----------+-------+------------------+---------+-----+-------+-------+---------+
| DateTime  | Side  | Identifier |   Color   | Level |       SDSa       | Current | LEF |  Sys  | Membr |   SDS   |
+-----------+-------+------------+-----------+-------+------------------+---------+-----+-------+-------+---------+
| 10/1/2018 | 15:01 | Left       | 107604736 | Red   | 0.65 5.053539157 |       0 |   0 | BOBJ7 |     5 |       1 |
| 10/2/2018 | 15:01 | Left       | 107604737 | Red   | 0.65 5.053539157 |  0.3035 |   1 | BOBJ8 |     6 | 0.98962 |
| 10/3/2018 | 15:01 | Left       | 107604738 | Red   | 0.65 5.053539157 |  0.6070 |   2 | BOBJ9 |     7 | 0.96576 |
+-----------+-------+------------+-----------+-------+------------------+---------+-----+-------+-------+---------+
```

I learned how to use

```
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(Data, '$.Measurements[1].SDS')) as X
```

A little bit in a query from digging, however, I do not know how to link other arrays in my result sets of the nested measurements in a json file that are of the same length. I would appreciate your help! Thanks!

PS: I am trying to create a view for others to query with this.

Here is an example of the document:

```
            {
              "DateTime": "10/1/2018 3:01:01 PM",
              "Side": "Left",
              "Identifier": "107604736",
              "Color": "Red",
              "Level": 0.65,
              "SDSa": 5.0535391569137573,
              "LEF": 0.0,
              "System": "BOBJ7",
              "Membrane": 5,
              "Current": [
                0.0,
                0.303535521,
                0.607071042,
                0.910606563,
                1.21414208,
                1.51767755,
                1.82121313,
                2.12474871,
                2.42828417,
                2.73181963,
                3.035355,
                3.33889079,
                3.64242625,
                3.94596171,
                4.24949741,
                4.553033,
                4.85656834,
                5.160104,
                5.46363926,
                5.76717472,
                6.07071,
                6.374246,
                6.67778158,
                6.981317,
                7.2848525,
                7.588388,
                7.89192343,
                8.195459,
                8.498995,
                8.80253,
                9.106066,
                9.409601,
                9.713137,
                10.0166721,
                10.3202076,
                10.6237431,
                10.9272785,
                11.230814,
                11.5343494,
                11.8378849,
                12.14142,
                12.4449568,
                12.7484922,
                13.0520277,
                13.3555632,
                13.6590986,
                13.9626341,
                14.26617,
                14.569705,
                14.87324,
                15.1767759,
                15.4803114,
                15.7838469,
                16.0873833,
                16.3909187,
                16.6944542,
                16.99799,
                17.3015251,
                17.60506,
                17.908596,
                18.2121315,
                18.515667,
                18.8192024,
                19.1227379,
                19.4262733,
                19.7298088,
                20.0333443,
                20.33688,
                20.6404152,
                20.94395,
                21.2474861,
                21.5510216,
                21.854557,
                22.1580925,
                22.461628,
                22.7651634,
                23.0686989,
                23.3722343,
                23.67577,
                23.9793053,
                24.28284,
                24.5863781,
                24.8899136,
                25.193449,
                25.4969845,
                25.80052,
                26.1040554,
                26.40759,
                26.7111263,
                27.0146618,
                27.3181973,
                27.6217327,
                27.9252682,
                28.2288036,
                28.53234,
                28.8358746,
                29.13941,
                29.4429455,
                29.74648,
                30.0500164
              ],
              "Measurements": [
                {
                  "FPOS": 1,
                  "Orient": "H",
                  "SDS50": 6.8644590377807617,
                  "ImageN": 0,
                  "SDS": [
                    1.0,
                    0.9896224,
                    0.9657684,
                    0.937525332,
                    0.9123899,
                    0.888601959,
                    0.8634422,
                    0.8382806,
                    0.8161909,
                    0.7984247,
                    0.7806436,
                    0.7606637,
                    0.739305735,
                    0.720110357,
                    0.7029224,
                    0.6836812,
                    0.660055459,
                    0.6333771,
                    0.6086391,
                    0.5865341,
                    0.5649619,
                    0.540699542,
                    0.5150109,
                    0.4912444,
                    0.470531732,
                    0.4510031,
                    0.429589,
                    0.407328546,
                    0.386515945,
                    0.369066834,
                    0.353259325,
                    0.336980551,
                    0.3197548,
                    0.302164435,
                    0.2844041,
                    0.264812022,
                    0.2432023,
                    0.221351326,
                    0.203265771,
                    0.190894246,
                    0.183355331,
                    0.178263873,
                    0.17374523,
                    0.169159114,
                    0.1635048,
                    0.15626812,
                    0.148360759,
                    0.141854659,
                    0.1383282,
                    0.136285663,
                    0.133377567,
                    0.127650827,
                    0.119844966,
                    0.111289464,
                    0.103005029,
                    0.09480265,
                    0.0866060555,
                    0.07927561,
                    0.0740468055,
                    0.07167137,
                    0.07141984,
                    0.07215432,
                    0.07259899,
                    0.07151956,
                    0.0681445152,
                    0.06242689,
                    0.05562524,
                    0.0492420681,
                    0.04441181,
                    0.0410645567,
                    0.0388742052,
                    0.0380086526,
                    0.03860841,
                    0.04033492,
                    0.04170464,
                    0.04166763,
                    0.0399215743,
                    0.0370087326,
                    0.0335897,
                    0.0301406663,
                    0.02666917,
                    0.023069948,
                    0.0193837862,
                    0.0161479469,
                    0.0140230907,
                    0.0133305294,
                    0.0137383873,
                    0.0145777585,
                    0.0155265825,
                    0.0166243,
                    0.01805606,
                    0.01932042,
                    0.0196347721,
                    0.01826151,
                    0.0154753188,
                    0.012052347,
                    0.008844916,
                    0.00625393027,
                    0.004384732,
                    0.00334442779
                  ],
                  "Processed": false
                },
                {
                  "FPOS": 2,
                  "Orient": "H",
                  "SDS50": 3.2426192760467529,
                  "ImageN": 0,
                  "SDS": [
                    1.0,
                    0.984369457,
                    0.940739632,
                    0.8834237,
                    0.8255927,
                    0.7736917,
                    0.7277459,
                    0.681687,
                    0.6329853,
                    0.582352459,
                    0.5328522,
                    0.48483035,
                    0.436798245,
                    0.388586164,
                    0.3424556,
                    0.302069068,
                    0.267472,
                    0.237092659,
                    0.209047124,
                    0.184123,
                    0.163114548,
                    0.144511625,
                    0.126265839,
                    0.107269846,
                    0.08942619,
                    0.07420107,
                    0.06193066,
                    0.0517099164,
                    0.0435060449,
                    0.0383287631,
                    0.0352067538,
                    0.03245497,
                    0.0286534447,
                    0.0242379941,
                    0.0201460086,
                    0.016266821,
                    0.0121985339,
                    0.008013846,
                    0.00560544431,
                    0.00502379332,
                    0.004533774,
                    0.004487538,
                    0.00551742641,
                    0.007546712,
                    0.009179788,
                    0.009129186,
                    0.007475236,
                    0.005305866,
                    0.004060863,
                    0.00462530646,
                    0.00631512143,
                    0.00748074846,
                    0.007632819,
                    0.006844715,
                    0.00562061928,
                    0.005166012,
                    0.006103046,
                    0.00768285431,
                    0.009006567,
                    0.009526576,
                    0.009514096,
                    0.009059127,
                    0.008065625,
                    0.006526997,
                    0.00434135273,
                    0.00191119267,
                    0.00254829624,
                    0.006861757,
                    0.0108742379,
                    0.0131905386,
                    0.013858974,
                    0.0132871456,
                    0.012235119,
                    0.01142512,
                    0.01094334,
                    0.0107232835,
                    0.0107062105,
                    0.010995524,
                    0.0112270387,
                    0.0102753676,
                    0.00612402242,
                    0.0010008571,
                    0.00318561238,
                    0.009038351,
                    0.0119382814,
                    0.0132263815,
                    0.013723935,
                    0.0133564435,
                    0.0129926438,
                    0.0127558094,
                    0.011888911,
                    0.009955382,
                    0.00670363754,
                    0.00246145763,
                    0.000897339836,
                    0.0037357898,
                    0.006457583,
                    0.007566943,
                    0.007532189,
                    0.006015837
                  ],
                  "Processed": false
                }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By taking the single row of data and cross joining the SDS and Current field, you get a recordset that repeats the data that is present one time and a combination of the Current and SDS values in the order they were provided.

```
DECLARE @test nvarchar(max)= N' {
              "DateTime": "10/1/2018 3:01:01 PM",
              "Side": "Left",
              "Identifier": "107604736",
              "Color": "Red",
              "Level": 0.65,
              "SDSa": 5.0535391569137573,
              "LEF": 0.0,
              "System": "BOBJ7",
              "Membrane": 5,
              "Current": [
                0.0,
                0.303535521,
                0.607071042,
                0.910606563,
                1.21414208,
                1.51767755,
                1.82121313,
                2.12474871,
                2.42828417,
                2.73181963,
                3.035355,
                3.33889079,
                3.64242625,
                3.94596171,
                4.24949741,
                4.553033,
                4.85656834,
                5.160104,
                5.46363926,
                5.76717472,
                6.07071,
                6.374246,
                6.67778158,
                6.981317,
                7.2848525,
                7.588388,
                7.89192343,
                8.195459,
                8.498995,
                8.80253,
                9.106066,
                9.409601,
                9.713137,
                10.0166721,
                10.3202076,
                10.6237431,
                10.9272785,
                11.230814,
                11.5343494,
                11.8378849,
                12.14142,
                12.4449568,
                12.7484922,
                13.0520277,
                13.3555632,
                13.6590986,
                13.9626341,
                14.26617,
                14.569705,
                14.87324,
                15.1767759,
                15.4803114,
                15.7838469,
                16.0873833,
                16.3909187,
                16.6944542,
                16.99799,
                17.3015251,
                17.60506,
                17.908596,
                18.2121315,
                18.515667,
                18.8192024,
                19.1227379,
                19.4262733,
                19.7298088,
                20.0333443,
                20.33688,
                20.6404152,
                20.94395,
                21.2474861,
                21.5510216,
                21.854557,
                22.1580925,
                22.461628,
                22.7651634,
                23.0686989,
                23.3722343,
                23.67577,
                23.9793053,
                24.28284,
                24.5863781,
                24.8899136,
                25.193449,
                25.4969845,
                25.80052,
                26.1040554,
                26.40759,
                26.7111263,
                27.0146618,
                27.3181973,
                27.6217327,
                27.9252682,
                28.2288036,
                28.53234,
                28.8358746,
                29.13941,
                29.4429455,
                29.74648,
                30.0500164
              ],
              "Measurements": [
                {
                  "FPOS": 1,
                  "Orient": "H",
                  "SDS50": 6.8644590377807617,
                  "ImageN": 0,
                  "SDS": [
                    1.0,
                    0.9896224,
                    0.9657684,
                    0.937525332,
                    0.9123899,
                    0.888601959,
                    0.8634422,
                    0.8382806,
                    0.8161909,
                    0.7984247,
                    0.7806436,
                    0.7606637,
                    0.739305735,
                    0.720110357,
                    0.7029224,
                    0.6836812,
                    0.660055459,
                    0.6333771,
                    0.6086391,
                    0.5865341,
                    0.5649619,
                    0.540699542,
                    0.5150109,
                    0.4912444,
                    0.470531732,
                    0.4510031,
                    0.429589,
                    0.407328546,
                    0.386515945,
                    0.369066834,
                    0.353259325,
                    0.336980551,
                    0.3197548,
                    0.302164435,
                    0.2844041,
                    0.264812022,
                    0.2432023,
                    0.221351326,
                    0.203265771,
                    0.190894246,
                    0.183355331,
                    0.178263873,
                    0.17374523,
                    0.169159114,
                    0.1635048,
                    0.15626812,
                    0.148360759,
                    0.141854659,
                    0.1383282,
                    0.136285663,
                    0.133377567,
                    0.127650827,
                    0.119844966,
                    0.111289464,
                    0.103005029,
                    0.09480265,
                    0.0866060555,
                    0.07927561,
                    0.0740468055,
                    0.07167137,
                    0.07141984,
                    0.07215432,
                    0.07259899,
                    0.07151956,
                    0.0681445152,
                    0.06242689,
                    0.05562524,
                    0.0492420681,
                    0.04441181,
                    0.0410645567,
                    0.0388742052,
                    0.0380086526,
                    0.03860841,
                    0.04033492,
                    0.04170464,
                    0.04166763,
                    0.0399215743,
                    0.0370087326,
                    0.0335897,
                    0.0301406663,
                    0.02666917,
                    0.023069948,
                    0.0193837862,
                    0.0161479469,
                    0.0140230907,
                    0.0133305294,
                    0.0137383873,
                    0.0145777585,
                    0.0155265825,
                    0.0166243,
                    0.01805606,
                    0.01932042,
                    0.0196347721,
                    0.01826151,
                    0.0154753188,
                    0.012052347,
                    0.008844916,
                    0.00625393027,
                    0.004384732,
                    0.00334442779
                  ],
                  "Processed": false
                },
                {
                  "FPOS": 2,
                  "Orient": "H",
                  "SDS50": 3.2426192760467529,
                  "ImageN": 0,
                  "SDS": [
                    1.0,
                    0.984369457,
                    0.940739632,
                    0.8834237,
                    0.8255927,
                    0.7736917,
                    0.7277459,
                    0.681687,
                    0.6329853,
                    0.582352459,
                    0.5328522,
                    0.48483035,
                    0.436798245,
                    0.388586164,
                    0.3424556,
                    0.302069068,
                    0.267472,
                    0.237092659,
                    0.209047124,
                    0.184123,
                    0.163114548,
                    0.144511625,
                    0.126265839,
                    0.107269846,
                    0.08942619,
                    0.07420107,
                    0.06193066,
                    0.0517099164,
                    0.0435060449,
                    0.0383287631,
                    0.0352067538,
                    0.03245497,
                    0.0286534447,
                    0.0242379941,
                    0.0201460086,
                    0.016266821,
                    0.0121985339,
                    0.008013846,
                    0.00560544431,
                    0.00502379332,
                    0.004533774,
                    0.004487538,
                    0.00551742641,
                    0.007546712,
                    0.009179788,
                    0.009129186,
                    0.007475236,
                    0.005305866,
                    0.004060863,
                    0.00462530646,
                    0.00631512143,
                    0.00748074846,
                    0.007632819,
                    0.006844715,
                    0.00562061928,
                    0.005166012,
                    0.006103046,
                    0.00768285431,
                    0.009006567,
                    0.009526576,
                    0.009514096,
                    0.009059127,
                    0.008065625,
                    0.006526997,
                    0.00434135273,
                    0.00191119267,
                    0.00254829624,
                    0.006861757,
                    0.0108742379,
                    0.0131905386,
                    0.013858974,
                    0.0132871456,
                    0.012235119,
                    0.01142512,
                    0.01094334,
                    0.0107232835,
                    0.0107062105,
                    0.010995524,
                    0.0112270387,
                    0.0102753676,
                    0.00612402242,
                    0.0010008571,
                    0.00318561238,
                    0.009038351,
                    0.0119382814,
                    0.0132263815,
                    0.013723935,
                    0.0133564435,
                    0.0129926438,
                    0.0127558094,
                    0.011888911,
                    0.009955382,
                    0.00670363754,
                    0.00246145763,
                    0.000897339836,
                    0.0037357898,
                    0.006457583,
                    0.007566943,
                    0.007532189,
                    0.006015837
                  ],
                  "Processed": false
                }]}';

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON(@test)
    WITH (
            DateTime nvarchar(max) '$.DateTime'
        ,   Side nvarchar(max) '$.Side'
        ,   Identifier nvarchar(max) '$.Identifier'
        ,   Color nvarchar(max) '$.Color'
        ,   Level nvarchar(max) '$.Level'
        ,   SDSa nvarchar(max) '$.SDSa'
        ,   Lef nvarchar(max) '$.LEF'
        ,   [Sys] nvarchar(max) '$.System'
        ,   Membr nvarchar(max) '$.Membrane'
    )
) baseData
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT CurrrentData.Value AS [CurrrentData],SdsData.Value AS [SdsData]
    FROM OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@test, '$.Current')) CurrrentData
    INNER JOIN OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@test, '$.Measurements[1].SDS')) SdsData ON SdsData.[key]=CurrrentData.[key]
) addlData
```

Comment: Thanks @UnhandledExcepSean! One more question: Is it even possible to get all of the SDSs in the document instead of the only at measurement [1]?

Comment: @Kevy I haven't worked too much with JSON in SQL Server, but I'm pretty sure it can be done.

Comment: Ok, I have been playing with this for some time now and cannot find anyway to translate this to query the column instead of a variable that's storing the json data. @UnhandledExcepSean this was everything I needed it to do and I want to thank you. Just I cannot get it to query a column instead in a table. Where I get stuck is when we cross join and to parse into that column. Everything above cross join works. Anyone have any ideas??

Comment: @kevy You need to post a new question with the exact problem you are having now

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Ok, will do.